# CallAjax with ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How I can add ID to Ajax:

```
    function callAjax()
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "topics.php?action=details&id=",
        cache: false,
        success: function(res){
                jQuery('#ajaxcontent').html(res);
        }
    });
}
```

With:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="'.$row['id'].'" class="button" onclick="callAjax();">'.$row['post_title'].'</a>
```

Thank in Advance for your support.

Comment: I highly recommend to read the [**jQuery tutorial**](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/#ajax-). May it help you to learn the basics about jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
url: "topics.php?action=details&id="+$('a').attr('id'),
```

if you want it to send in data.then use like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "topics.php",
      data: { action: "details", id: $('a').attr('id') },
        cache: false,
        success: function(res){
                jQuery('#ajaxcontent').html(res);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding ...

```
data: { id: "MyIdHere" },
```

... this data is then formatted and sent correctly as a part of the GET.

This can be removed from the URL ... and also added as part of the data:

```
?action=details&id=
```

... like this ...

```
data: { action: "details", id: "MyIdHere" },
```